# How to define a custom TypeScript definition of an array where all elements are number except first

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

The arrays in question are SVG path segments, for instance `['L', 0, 0]` I'm basically using this to define these arrays:

```js
// doSomethingToSegment.js

/** @type {Object.<string, number>} */
const paramsCount = {
  a: 7, c: 6, h: 1, l: 2, m: 2, r: 4, q: 4, s: 4, t: 2, v: 1, z: 0,
};
  
/**
 * This definition is WRONG, FIX ME!!
 *
 * @typedef {(string|number)[]} segment
 */

/**
 * Check segment validity.
 *
 * @param {segment} seg input segment
 * @return {boolean} segment is/not valid
 */
function checkSegment(seg) {
  const [pathCommand] = seg;
  const LK = pathCommand.toLowerCase();
  const UK = pathCommand.toUpperCase();
  const segmentValues = seg.slice(1);
  const expectedAmount = paramsCount[LK];

  return checkPathCommand(UK) && checkPathValues(segmentValues, expectedAmount);
}

/**
 * @param {string} ch input character
 * @returns {boolean} true when `ch` is path command
 */
function checkPathCommand(ch) {
  return ('ACHLMRQSTVZ').includes(ch);
}

/**
 * @param {Number[]} values input values
 * @param {Number} expected amount
 * @return {boolean} segment has/not the right amount of valid numbers
 */
function checkPathValues(values, expected) {
  return values.length === expected && values.every(x => !Number.isNaN(x));
}
```

Now the `pathCommand.toLowerCase()` call throws this error:

```
Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'string | number'.
  Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

And the `segmentValues` throws this one:

```
Argument of type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
  Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

So, how to define a custom type definition `@type {WHAT} segment)` that satisfies this specific need?

Comment: Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVgbvm) maybe?  But what is `someVar` and `otherVar`?  And a [mre] should not have typos or other unrelated problems (like `typedef` instead of `@typedef`).  Please fix the code to demonstrate your exact issue, since it seems like you might have an issue with stuff inside the *implementation* of `doSomethingToSegment` instead of *callers* to it.

Comment: You example looks good, thanks. Why you didn't post an answer so I can mark it green?

Comment: I'm happy to, but I don't know what `someVar.toFixed(3)` is going to do, and I'm concerned that I'll post an answer and you'll have a follow-up question about this bit.  If it's not important, then maybe remove it from the question? If it is important, could you flesh it out with a code example?

Comment: Edited the question, `someVar.toFixed()` is really not important, it's about any numeric operation with string type variables or when `someVar` is used as a parameter in a function expecting a number..

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what `someVar` is; your code doesn't define it. If it's not important, you can remove it from your question. To the extent that it *is* important, you can write a [mre] that actually demonstrates the issue instead of just alluding to it.  And you've still got `segment` undefined in the code because of a typo.  The existing answer is apparently good for you, and you've edited that.  Now could you edit your question to improve it so that future viewers can have a good Q/A pair? Thanks!

Comment: Or, if you don't mind, I will edit your question.  I don't like to do that myself without permission.

Comment: I'm editing right now, it's really hard to make a most simple example so it's not a burden to anyone to might want to provide an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @jcalz done. Have it your way with any edits you feel.

Comment: Ah, this is what I was worried about.  Note that [even the suggested type](https://tsplay.dev/mAvrBW) doesn't resolve all your errors.  Now the question is: does the accepted answer *really* suffice for you, given that your [mre] is not error-free with it?  If so, then I will be happy to jump in here with my editing scythe and fix the example to not have an error.  On the other hand, if the answer does *not* suffice, then you probably should not have accepted it in the first place. It's [solvable](https://tsplay.dev/mpv86w), but I don't know the right way to proceed here now. 

Comment: Go right ahead, I might learn something I didn't know exist :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type A = [string, ...number[]];
```

More info about rest elements in tuple types:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types

Here are examples from the docs:

> Tuples can also have rest elements, which have to be an array/tuple
> type.
>
> ```
> type StringNumberBooleans = [string, number, ...boolean[]];
> type StringBooleansNumber = [string, ...boolean[], number];
> type BooleansStringNumber = [...boolean[], string, number];
> ```

Comment: Quick question: can this get adopted for Tuple objects? Something like `{type: string, ...{string, number}[]}`, I was testing everything didn't get it to work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand it. Maybe you could post a new Stack Overflow question with a bit more detail?

Comment: The exact same thing but for objects, instead of `[string, ...number[]]` is it possible to have something like `{myString: string, ...{string, number}[]]`.